# Selenium web application testing with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to assert whether my text fields are empty in my web application but I don't know how to go about it. A little help here could help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Get Attribute value of text field:-**

```
 String expectedvalue="your expected value";
 WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xapth("path of your element")).sendkey("Actual value");
 String attributevalue=element.getAttribute("Value");

 System.out.println(attributevalue);

  if(attributevalue.equals(expectedvalue)){
    //Text box is not empty
}
  else{
    //textbox is empty

    }
```

Note:-code is written in java change in C#

Answer (score 0):

First you need to grab the element representing the text field.
Then you can store this in a IWebElement variable.
So:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.xpath("//div[@textField='text']")).Text;
```

now you can compare this value with your expected value (i.e. empty) after converting your IWebElement to a string.

```
IList<string> comparison = new List<string>();
foreach(var element in driver.FindElements(By.xpath("yourXpath"));
{
    comparison.Add(element.Text);
}

Assert.AreEqual(comparison, "")
```